# How to relay Nagios information to a central location?

Tags: nagios

I have Nagios running to monitor a number of various local services. I am trying to figure out a way to have Nagios monitor network connectivity between two remote locations and report that information back to my Nagios server to be included in my list of monitored services.

For example: Let's say my company has a VPN connection between our California office and our New York office. The New York office has a VPN connection with our Seattle office. I want to monitor the connection (something as simple as a ping at regular intervals) between the New York and Seattle office and have this information relayed back to the Nagios server at my California office so that I can view that information with the rest of my locally monitored services.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/distributed.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is [NSCA](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/NSCA--2D-Nagios-Service-Check-Acceptor/details). On the central Nagios server you create all the hosts and services you want to monitor, but don't enable active checks. You also need to enable passive check results in the main Nagios configuration.

The "distributed" Nagios instances then need to use NSCA to submit service check results to the central host.